# Unable find the right encoding for a HTML -file in Vim

Tags: html, vim, encoding

I see

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bug-enc.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/bug-enc.png)

where all contents is in one line.

It seems that this is the reason of bad encoding. I can see the characters `^M`.

**How can you get the encoding right in Vim?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
:set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
```

Then reread your file with `:e`.

Comment: I opened another similar question at http://serverfault.com/questions/35900/unable-to-find-the-right-fileformat-for-screens-logs-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

These are "line breaks", or [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

From your screenshot it seems the file uses Mac-style line breaks, which are a single carriage return (`0x0D`, in the screenshot shown as `^M`).

Windows (and most of the Internet protocols) use both carriage return and line feed (`0x0D 0x0A`), and Unix uses a single line feed (`0x0A`) to separate lines. Macs used to only use carriage returns (now Unix-style is common on MacOS X too).

In vi/vim, try this command to make it recognize the file:

```
:set ff=mac
```

You can try using this command to convert the file to Windows-style line breaks:

```
sed "s/\x0D/\x0D\x0A/g" yourfile.html > yourfile.new.html
```