# Unable to find the right fileformat for Screen's logs in Vim

Tags: vim, encoding

I see

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/fileformat-problem.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/fileformat-problem.png)

where I have `^M` and `^[` at various places. The former seems to be enter, while the latter apparently the end/beginning of the line.

I would like to get the purple symbols out such that I can read the log -file better.

[I run](https://serverfault.com/questions/35836/unable-find-the-right-encoding-for-a-html-file-in-vim/35839#35839)

```
:set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
:e
```

but I get the same output.

**How can you get the encoding/fileformat right?**

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information about vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[` is another representation for `Escape` (pressing Ctrl-[ is the same as pressing the escape key - the carat represents the control key). These are the beginning of ANSI color sequences. I don't think vim is going to show those colors (unless there's a filter that processes them).

There is a plugin for `vim` called [AnsiEsc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) that will display the results of ANSI color sequences in a file. In order to install that plugin, you'll need to install the [Vimball](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502) plugin first. In order to take *full* advantage of AnsiEsc, you'll need to recompile `vim` with the patch described on the AnsiEsc page.

You have to set the fileformats before the file is loaded (or in your .vimrc file). It won't apply it to a file that's already loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! --- You can see Screen's logs clearly by `cat screenlog.0 | less -r`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can run s/\^M//g and s/\^[//g in vi to remove the offending characters but doesn't resolve the issue with the file handling. Do you know what encoding the file is using? You can guess by using `file` and it will give you info such as: "`ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`"

**NOTE:** To enter the "^M" as "CTRL-V CTRL-M"

Comment: @Chealion: I have tried to use only the `fileformat=unix`. The file is screenlog.0 so the file extension is .0. --- Your command gives me `screenlog.0: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with CRLF, CR line terminators, with escape sequences, with overstriking`.

Comment: @Chealion: note that the "fileformat" option is different from the "fileformats" (plural) option. The former affects file writing; the latter affects file reading.

Comment: @Greg My bad. Cleaned up my answer without the unnecessary bits.

Answer (score 0):

if it is an option you could try dos2unix (and its partner in crime unix2dos)